# Extract all text before matched text until another match

Tags: regex, bash, text, awk, sed

I am trying extract text from "multipath -l" command output with a regex to get all text (including the lines of matched text) between matched disk device name e.g. "sdaf" and match backwards up to the next line starting with mpath (in this case mpathf). The number of lines is varying so I cannot use "grep -B".

So from this example

```
mpatha (360060160e6e04400e819a6ac680fe811) dm-7 DGC,VRAID
size=50G features='1 queue_if_no_path' hwhandler='1 emc' wp=rw
|-+- policy='round-robin 0' prio=0 status=active
| |- 0:0:6:0  sdw  65:96  active undef running
| `- 0:0:5:0  sdt  65:48  active undef running
`-+- policy='round-robin 0' prio=0 status=enabled
  |- 0:0:4:0  sdq  65:0   active undef running
  `- 0:0:7:0  sdz  65:144 active undef running
mpathf (36006016016003f00cf52bfe07b10e811) dm-2 DGC,VRAID
size=50G features='1 queue_if_no_path' hwhandler='1 emc' wp=rw
|-+- policy='round-robin 0' prio=0 status=active
| |- 0:0:1:20 sdh  8:112  active undef running
| |- 2:0:9:20 sdan 66:112 active undef running
| |- 0:0:2:20 sdl  8:176  active undef running
| `- 2:0:6:20 sdav 66:240 active undef running
`-+- policy='round-robin 0' prio=0 status=enabled
  |- 0:0:0:20 sdd  8:48   active undef running
  |- 2:0:8:20 sdaj 66:48  active undef running
  |- 0:0:3:20 sdp  8:240  active undef running
  |- 2:0:7:20 sdar 66:176 active undef running
  `- 2:0:5:20 sdaf 65:240 active undef running
```

I want to get text

```
mpathf (36006016016003f00cf52bfe07b10e811) dm-2 DGC,VRAID
size=50G features='1 queue_if_no_path' hwhandler='1 emc' wp=rw
|-+- policy='round-robin 0' prio=0 status=active
| |- 0:0:1:20 sdh  8:112  active undef running
| |- 2:0:9:20 sdan 66:112 active undef running
| |- 0:0:2:20 sdl  8:176  active undef running
| `- 2:0:6:20 sdav 66:240 active undef running
`-+- policy='round-robin 0' prio=0 status=enabled
  |- 0:0:0:20 sdd  8:48   active undef running
  |- 2:0:8:20 sdaj 66:48  active undef running
  |- 0:0:3:20 sdp  8:240  active undef running
  |- 2:0:7:20 sdar 66:176 active undef running
  `- 2:0:5:20 sdaf 65:240 active undef running
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am a bit unclear of why would you require a regex to do so, cause to get that desired output you just have to use this expression "mpathf (.|\n)*" (which is not really that complicated)

Comment: So I don't know which mpath_ it is. That is the information I am actually looking for. Under which mpath_ is this particular device (sdaf)

Comment: so you want to extract the content inside the parenthesis "(36006016016003f00cf52bfe07b10e811)" or including the nested information + each branch parsed?

Answer (score 0):

I can achieve it by storing lines in a variable. I reset it or print it when needed.

multipath.awk :

```
        {output = output "\n" $0}   /* store line in variable */
/^mpath/ {output = $0}              /* reset buffer */
/sdaf/   {print output}             /* print buffer */
```

I get your result with the file `multipath.txt` that corresponds to your example (I have not installed multipath tool). I launched it with :

```
awk -f multipath.awk multipath.txt
```

You can write awk command in one line:

```
 multipath -l | awk    '{output = output "\n" $0}   /^mpath/ {output = $0}   /sdaf/   {print output}'
```

Comment: Possible to have a one-liners for this?